# Laravel - Handle static file download using Web Server instead of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It seems that Laravel serves all requests including simple static file downloads by it's own.

So in a simple web page request that might have tens of assets, each request will start a php process.

One of the main advantages people discuss when choosing nginx over apache is higher performance in serving large numbers of static file, so when using Laravel, are those static files loaded as dynamic php files?

Comment: Why do you think Laravel handles requests to static files?

Comment: Modify your webserver configuration to handle static files if necessary; or use a front-end proxy

Comment: @lukasgeiter because it seems that it rewrites every request to the server, to index.php using it's htaccess file, and also, it shows it's own 404 - not found when a file is not found (instead of apache's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the default `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The important part are the two `RewriteCond`itions. As you can see if the request is a file or directory it won't rewrite to index.php. So you don't have to worry if you're requesting a static file, Laravel will not bootstrap.

**Regarding the 404 Error**
It shows the Laravel error page because if the file can't be found the RewriteCondition will let it through to `index.php`